Authorization in ActiveMQ Artemis using Keycloak
I'm making an experiment: I'm trying to do authorization in ActiveMQ Artemis using Keycloak. Finally I want to have something like this: when user enter something like :8161 he gets to the Keycloak authorization page and, if his user is allowed access according to the Keycloak settings, he gets to the Artemis web page.
Now I'm trying to do it in my local machine. I have made all the settings, but I get an error in the Artemis container logs:
2024-11-07 14:30:53,852 WARN  [io.hawt.system.JaasAuthenticator] Login failed due to: No LoginModule found for org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.DirectAccessGrantsLoginModule

What can I do with it ?
My docker-compose file:
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
   image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.0
   container_name: keycloak
   restart: unless-stopped
   environment:
      - KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN=http://localhost:8080
      - KC_HOSTNAME=http://localhost:8080
      - KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=public
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - KC_DB_URL_HOST=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - KC_LOG_LEVEL=ALL
   depends_on:
      - postgres
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   command: start-dev
   volumes:
      - ./keycloak_data/auth/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.0
    container_name: postgres-keycloak
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5436:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      
      
  artemis:
    image: apache/activemq-artemis:2.37.0
    container_name: artemis
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
         - KEYCLOAK_ENABLED=true
         - ARTEMIS_USER=admin
         - ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "8161:8161" 
      - "61616:61616"
    volumes:
      - ./artemis_data:/var/lib/artemis/etc

In ActiveMQ Artemis container I've created keycloak.json:
{
  "realm": "artemis",
  "resource": "artemis-web",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "DD91ch9wpGbs2gRkMjsp3sdabt52mQlc"
  }
}



login.config:
 activemq {
      org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.DirectAccessGrantsLoginModule required
      keycloak-config-file="/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/keycloak.json"
      role-principal-class=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal;
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PrincipalConversionLoginModule required
      principalClassList=org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal;
};


I don't know what's wrong here.
P.S. I saw one detail. When I'm starting container with ActiveMQ Artemis in container logs I can see this:
2024-11-07 14:30:52,454 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled

Maybe I can enable integration and all my problems will be solved ? But I don't know how to enable it.

Any feedback here?

The login module you're attempting to use (i.e. org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.DirectAccessGrantsLoginModule) is not shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis which means you need to add it to the broker's classpath yourself (e.g. adding it to the broker's lib directory).
Here is an example of how this was fixed for ActiveMQ Artemis operator.

Does it mean that I can't use login modules in ActiveMQ Artemis in docker and I must use ActiveMQ Artemis Kubernetes ?

No, that's not what it means. The login modules are just Java classes and can be used in any deployment/environment that supports the broker. The link to the operator simply demonstrates another instance of this problem and how it was solved by adding the correct jars to the broker's classpath. In your case, you simply need to add the jar containing org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.DirectAccessGrantsLoginModule to your broker's classpath in Docker.

You need to enable Keycloak integration by adding to your JAVA_ARGS to artemis.profile: -Dhawtio.keycloakEnabled=true
See more detailed: JMS Security Keycloak Example
